# django form sends empty request on IE - weird error

Tags: django, internet-explorer

So I have built a site on my workplace network using django and deploying it with wamp. I don't have a direct connection from my workplace to the internet so I can't show any actual code (not without taking some time to print and rewrite everything).

Now ever since I deployed the site I have been facing one of the worst and weirdes bugs I have ever encountered. It happens only on IE and not even all the time.

what happens is I created a modelform (I added a few lines to make it nicer, but nothing complicated that I couldn't handle on the validation part), and just put it in a template as is. I have added a csrf token and everything seems to be in order.

That is until you click on sending the data. That's when he sends - for some reason, a completely empty request. I don't mean he sends an empty form - he sends a request without any data at **all**. First I thought it had something to do with the jquery UI I have (just for adding dates), or the csrf going weird but ommiting them didn't change anything (as in, when you omit the csrf token and middlewere it acts as if you sent an empty form, but when it's enabled it acts as if the csrf caught an exeption - because an empty request means no value for the csrf hidden field).

I actually used wireshark and caught the error and ... that's it. I'm no closer to solving it. I tried everything, from changing the page to quirks mode, to rewriting all the html to writing several different template versions just to see what happens.

And It's driving me insane becuase this doesn't even happen all the time. I know I mentioned that already but I just can't make any sense of it. And before you ask - no, it's not an option to use a different webbrowser because all the web-apps my company uses are fit to work with IE and most people here are not technological enough to use multiple browsers.

one more important thing that might help - the bug almost always happens the first time you visit the page (or when you open it in a new tab). If, say, you already went back and forth a few times in the same tab, it usually works fine. we're using IE8, on windows xp computers. Any help would be extremely appreciated, thanks!

Comment: did 'you' try it in a different browser,before settling it as an IE error?

Comment: yes. running tests on chrome, firefox and opera worked fine. definetly an IE problem